# How to write a Linq statement in SQL?

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm fairly new to using Linq in C# and I just want to know how a normal SQL statement will look like when compared to a Linq query?

**I have this statement:**

```
var query =
from b in db.Employee.Include(o => o.Position)
where b.Position.Position_Desc == "Junior" && b.Employee_ID == 5
select b;
```

So my actual question is *how* will this statement look if I were to write it in **SQL**?

Comment: You can execute this code against a real SQL server and use SQL profiler to see the actual SQL query

Answer (score 1):

`query.ToString()` should return the SQL.

Or you can use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

Answer (score 0):

If there is a relation between `Employees` and `Positions` tables with foreign key say `Employees.PositionId -> Positions.Id`. Then you can use `LEFT JOIN` to write a similar SQL query:

```
SELECT Employees.*,
       Positions.*
FROM Employees
LEFT JOIN Positions ON Employees.PositionId = Positions.Id
WHERE Positions.Position_Desc = 'Junior'
      AND Employees.Employee_ID = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your query in debug mode (see attach image)

[image]